# Data send by node js get route is displayed in Angular app if ctrl + R is pressed

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, angular5

Hy i am working on a MEAN app with angular 5 and i have a question cause i'am kind of stuck on this. I want to retrive the users from my database and i can do that no problem but if the client presses ctrl + R to refresh the page (i don't know why let's assume it does) all the data that i recive from my backend is displayed.
I  don't know how can i avoid this and alsow i don;t have anyone to consult.
Here is my code:

> User service.ts

```
  getUsers() {
const url = '/profile';
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this._httpClient.get(url, {headers: headers})
  .map((res) => res);
```

}

> some.component.ts

```
this._userService.getUsers().subscribe(
  (users) => {
    this.users = users;
  }
)
```

> app.js

```
  > const app = express();
    const profileRoute= require('./routes/profile');

    app.use(profileRoute);   // THE PROBLEM IS HERE IF I PUT THIS AFTER app.get('*') THE ANGULAR GET REQUEST WILL NOT REACH THE SERVERS PROFILE ROUTE
    // Send all other requests to Angular app/////
    app.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'));
    });
```

> backend profile route:

```
router.get('/profile', (req,res) =>{
        User.find({}).exec().then((users) =>{
            if(users !== undefined) {
                res.send(users);
            }
        })
    });
```

> data displayed if ctrl + R is pressed
>   [image]

Comment: Do you want to display the data on page refresh or not?

Comment: @Abhijit Kar no i don't, i have found the problem but i don't know how to ghe around this:  i am using profile route before this line app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'));
}); But if i put the profile route after this the angular get request will not reach this point

Comment: @Abhijit Kar i've reedited a a bit the code added the app.js and a part of the problem